# Error on any FBX import or export on Blender 3.6

Tags: python, export, import, error, .fbx

Whenever I try to import or export a model, I get this error:
[image: Error I get on import or export]

I have tried rein-stalling blender, and the same thing happens. This has only happened recently, and I did not modify Blender in any way that I know of. It just seemingly happened on its own.

I have Blender installed through Steam, so I don't know if that would cause an issue.
My other version of blender (2.8) is still totally fine, so this is specific to that installation in particular.

This happens with ALL FBX files, even ones I've exported from that same project previously.

Thank you in advance to anyone who might know a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this later: I found out it was one of my addons. I don't know which one, but I disabled literally every addon that isn't built in and it works now. I'll have to figure out the exact cause and specific addon later, but at least I know not to trust the error message.